# Xcode 6 GM Seed - iPhone 6 simulator does not show the home button

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6, home-button

I am creating a game in Xcode-6-GM-Seed and am having an issue that the home button is not showing up in the simulator.

I need to be able to press the home button to be able to quickly delete the app from the phone but am not seeing the home button.

How do I get around this? Is there some sort of command to use or do I need to do it programmatically until they add the home button? Is there another way to delete the app and it's content?

[image: Image of the Simulator:]

Comment: Does the Home (shift-cmd-H) command work from the hardware menu?

Comment: well, this was the same situation for retina simulators/ipads in xcode 5 too..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Command + Shift + H for pressing Home button.

You can also choose "Reset Content and Settings" to erase the App.

Comment: Great that worked! I need to wait 10 min to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, shift+command+h is how you should trigger the home button to get to SpringBoard.

If you need to uninstall an app, you can also do that from the command line via simctl:

xcrun simctl uninstall booted com.mycompany.myapp